# How to display image with fancybox href attribute

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am trying to show image with fancybox 1.3 . I have managed to do this with base64 coding, it worked like a charm. But now, I want to retrieve the image through a servlet. If i put the url to the image src attribute, it shows the image, but if I put this url to the href attribute, when I click on the picture it shows this:

[image]

I set the response content type correctly. What can be the problem?

Comment: Just make sure you add `type: "image"` in your fancybox API options within your custom fancybox initialization scritp

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an example to display base64 image with fancy box**

you don't need any `<a>` tag

```
<div class="content">
<img  src="data:image/gif;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...." alt="social media" >
<img  src="data:image/gif;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...." alt="james bond;" >
 </div>
```

jquery

```
  $('.content').on('click', 'img', function (e) {

    var tarGet= $(this).attr("src");
    var imgtitle= $(this).attr("alt");
     $.fancybox({             

                'overlayShow': true,
                'href': tarGet,
                'titlePosition': 'inside',                
                'title': imgtitle,               
            });  
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

add 'type': "image"

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
                    'titlePosition'  : 'over',
                    'type': "image",
                })
```